# Selectable input fields and textareas but no other content selectable in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, firefox-3

I need to prevent users from selecting elements in my web app UI, *except* for text in input fields and textareas.  For Firefox, the technique seems to be to use this css:

```
* { -moz-user-select: none; }
```

And that works well enough (tested Firefox 3.5.2), except that you cannot then select within input fields or textareas.

I tried dividing it into

```
div,td,span,img { -moz-user-select: none; }
input,textarea { -moz-user-select: text; }
```

however, if the input field is inside of a div, td, or span, it is not selectable.  It seems that the -moz-user-select property is applied to all children as well, no matter if those children override the setting.  Does anyone know a way around this aside from setting this at a far more granular (and annoying) level for specific elements?

**NOTE** this is not for security purposes.  I am fine having users view source or advanced users turning this off.  But for web UI's with drag-and-drop functionality, or just those that are supposed to behave like an application in general rather than like a document, it is really weird to be able to accidentally select text.  And it happens often for most users.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
* { -moz-user-select: -moz-none; }
input,textarea { -moz-user-select: text; }
```

Comment: ah crap, I just realized I had "none" not "-moz-none".  Awarding you the bounty I just assigned as soon as I'm allowed to!!

Answer (score 1):

You are fighting a lost cause.  If I really want to select text from your page, or get it in some way, I will.

However, on to your question.  Try adding !important to the end, so it looks like this:

```
div,td,span,img { -moz-user-select: none; }
input,textarea { -moz-user-select: text !important; }
```

Comment: It is not for security purposes and I don't care if the user views source or anything.  It is because for some reason people keep accidentally selecting stuff and it is goofy because this is a Application and in general selecting ui elements ("buttons" formed of composite html elements for instance) feels clunky...

Comment: ..oh, and more importantly, !important didn't seem to help, I did try that, should have mentioned!  thank you though